# I would like to export wordpress template :

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm doing now in this way:
 1. tool ->export xml (posts, pages, comments, custom fields, terms, navigation menus and custom posts)
 2. install all required plugins
 3. tool ->widget export
 4. export widgets

MY question is: IS there way to export all things using only one plugin export?
I dont like to backup database and do many exports, just to export and import one file.
Does anybody knows about such plugin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check out [WP-DB-Back-up](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-db-backup/) plugin.

Comment: it can backup the d not the plugins